# Monogdb MMS Shutting down monitoring to `ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:27017`: no longer present

Tags: mongodb-mms

Below are the logs for from mongo mms agent, not sure why it stopped monitoring suddenly

```
[2014/07/08 17:49:33] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:145] Sent all 1     host requests to channel. Awaiting responses...
[2014/07/08 17:49:33] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:279] Posting final ping payload containing 1/1 hosts
[2014/07/08 17:49:33] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:323] Done. Sleeping for 54.3s...
[2014/07/08 17:50:28] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:145] Sent all 1 host requests to channel. Awaiting responses...
[2014/07/08 17:50:28] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:279] Posting final ping payload containing 1/1 hosts
[2014/07/08 17:50:28] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:323] Done. Sleeping for 54.3s...
[2014/07/08 17:51:23] [monitoring.routinemanager.info] [monitoring-agent/components/bus.go:49] Shutting down monitoring to `ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:27017`: no longer present
[2014/07/08 17:51:23] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:297] Nothing to do. Either the server detected the possibility of another monitoring agent running, or no Hosts are configured on the MMS group.
[2014/07/08 17:51:23] [monitoring.process-ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:27017.info] [monitoring-agent/components/bus.go:149] Received quit to shutdown all 3 monitors
[2014/07/08 17:51:23] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:323] Done. Sleeping for 54.6s...
[2014/07/08 17:52:18] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:297] Nothing to do. Either the server detected the possibility of another monitoring agent running, or no Hosts are configured on the MMS group.
[2014/07/08 17:52:18] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:323] Done. Sleeping for 54.7s...
[2014/07/08 17:53:13] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:297] Nothing to do. Either the server detected the possibility of another monitoring agent running, or no Hosts are configured on the MMS group.
[2014/07/08 17:53:13] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:323] Done. Sleeping for 54.6s...
[2014/07/08 17:54:08] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:297] Nothing to do. Either the server detected the possibility of another monitoring agent running, or no Hosts are configured on the MMS group.
```

Comment: Can you try doing a ping to the ip:port and see if you are getting response back.

Comment: This is private ip, i cannot ping from outside, but from this ip can call outside world urls. My application is working fine doing CRUD operations.

Comment: This not really a programming question as such it belongs better on maybe Super User or dba SE

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into a similar issue.

In my case the server had been down for too long and was deactivated in MMS. On the deployment page on MMS, click the warning icon and then click 'reactivate all instances'.